# return string of odd elements in a linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, tostring

I need to write a method that – returns a string with the odd elements’ toStrings concatenated with a colon between. In other words, the 1st, 3rd, 5th, … elements.

I have already written a method(s) to return a string of all elements:

```
public String toString (Node<E> node) {
    if (node == null) {
        return "";
    }
    else {
        Node<E> next = node.next ();
        return node.element () + (next == null ? "" : "\n") + toString (next);
    }
}
//Return String with all elements
public String toString() {
    return toString(head);
}
```

This code hasn't been tested..

This is my first time working with linked lists so i'm not sure if there is a simple one-liner to accomplish this or what is the logic i need to use?

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: I like the recursive approach you used here. But for every other element, it might be easier to look into `for` loops.

Comment: Why have you not tested it?

Comment: @peeskillet - I think it is an unfortunate choice to call a method **with non-void arguments** toString; `oddElementsAsString` would seem a better name (and it should be static, since it receives an argument)

Comment: @jonhopkins yea thats what I was leaning towards, but my problem really comes in the logic, does the linked list have a way to grab every other element or how would this be done?

Comment: Now that I think about it, I don't know if your `Node` class has a `length` property, so a `while` loop might be better. But I would just do it with a counter that increments every iteration of the loop, and every other loop you add to the string.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code a bit in order to work properly:

```
public String toString (Node<E> node) {
    if (node == null) {
        return "";
    }
    else {
        Node<E> next = node.next ();
        if(next == null){
           return node.element().toString(); //avoid null pointer exceptions
        }

        return node.element () + "\n" + toString(next.next());//continue recursion with an odd element
    }
}
```

This code can be improved.

Answer (score 0):

For getting every other element in a linked list, I would use a `while` loop with a counter to keep track of which element we're on so only the correct elements are added to the string. Since even numbers can easily be denoted by `number % 2 == 0` and odd numbers by `number % 2 == 1`, it is trivial to figure out whether the current node is even or odd as long as the counter is up to date.

In this example, the loop must go through every node in the list and add to the string only when the counter is even (or odd if you want to change it to that).

```
public String toString(Node<E> node) {
    if (node == null) {
        return "";
    }

    String elements = ""; // I would recommend looking into StringBuilder
    int counter = 0;

    // add the first element to the string right away.
    // this will eliminate accidentally putting a \n at the beginning
    // of the string, before any elements have been added to it
    elements = node.element; // if you want odd elements instead of 
    node = node.next();      // even, swap these two lines.
    counter++;

    while (node != null) {
        if (counter % 2 == 0) { // only add the even elements
                                // this can easily be changed for odd elements
            elements = elements + "\n" + node.element;
        }
        node = node.next(); // go to the next node every iteration of the loop
        counter++; // always increment the counter
    }

    return elements;
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks I was over complicating it, as always. I do have one questions, on elements = node.element; I get a type mismatch error, I fixed it with casting elements = (String) node.element... but is this the right fix or is something else wrong there?

Comment: It depends on what `node.element` actually is. If it's working, chances are that that's the right fix. I would only be concerned about casting to `String` if `element` is an object of some sort.